# Can i put planks on wood lath on my ceiling in the living room?

Tags: repair, ceiling

My plaster was falling apart on the ceiling. So we decided to take it down. I don't want to do drywall or plasterboard. Is there any way I could do planks or something else?

Comment: You can put darn near anything you want on your ceiling.

Comment: So for like a rustic look I would just get some wooden oldish looking planks and get screws and put them up. I know I need a chalk line and drill. Idk I'm a beginner 

Comment: @Amy, if you want rustic getting some "oldish" planks is a start.  You may be better to nail rather than screw.   Often ceiling wood is thin and light, because it is decorative and has no structural purpose.  If needed you could rent or purchase a battery powered FINISH nail gun.

Comment: You can use lightweight planks or whatnot, but you'll need to learn a little about the techniques...especially before buying tools.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can.  Depending on your design tastes and talents, you can make a ceiling that looks Rustic, Formal, Casual, and many other styles.

If you need advice on how to actually install planks, decide on a style and ask a new question specifically about what you need to know for your desired ceiling.

Comment: online image search for more ideas "shiplap ceiling" (in the interest of getting OP started down the rabbit hole)